# Managing multiple instances of HttpClient using Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, dotnet-httpclient, simple-injector, ambiguous

I'm creating an instance of `HttpClient` for each distinct API that my web application is communicating to.

I want to use Dependency Injection with [SimpleInjector](https://simpleinjector.org/index.html) to inject `HttpClient` to the business classes. For example, I have `ITwitterBusiness` and `IInstagramBusiness`, and both of them accept `HttpClient` in their constructor.

What is the best practice when it comes to registering multiple objects of the same type using Dependency Injection?

I'm pretty sure that part of the problem could be my design, but here are some ideas.

**My first idea is to use delegate in the DI registration**

```
container.Register<ITwitterBusiness>(() => new TwitterBusiness(httpClientTwitter));
```

Seems simple enough, but I don't know if this method has any bad side effects, for example by making SimpleInjector run slower or if I'm breaking some design pattern.

**My second idea is to use Context based injection** http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#context-based-injection

I believe this will allow me to inject a certain HttpClient instance to a certain class. Still not exactly sure how this works.

I'm very curious if I could solve this purely by design. For example by creating dummy classes. I just haven't found any good examples, but If I understand it correctly then I could create dummy classes such as `HttpClientTwitter` that inherits `HttpClient`, and that way I can get rid of the ambiguous registration.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My first idea is to use delegate in the DI registration. Seems simple enough, but I don't know if this method has any bad side effects, for example by making SimpleInjector run slower or if I'm breaking some design pattern.

The use of auto-wiring (the opposite of registering a delegate) is advised in case the type has any application components that need to be wired. Auto-wiring simplifies registration and allows Simple Injector to analyse the object graph. Both seem to be of no concern in your case. The `HttpClient` is not an application component, but an infrastructure type. There seem to be no other dependencies, so registering a delegate doesn't pose any maintainability issues.

Delegate registration is slower compared to the use of auto-wiring, Simple Injector isn't able to optimize as much using delegates. It is however very, *very* unlikely that you notice any performance difference when doing this. This is not something you should worry about.

> My second idea is to use Context based injection. I believe this will allow me to inject a certain HttpClient instance to a certain class. Still not exactly sure how this works.

You can make distinct registrations based on the context. For instance:

```
var httpClientTwitterRegistration = Lifestyle.Transient.CreateRegistration<HttpClient>(
    () => new HttpClient("https://twitter"),
    container);

container.RegisterConditional(typeof(HttpClient), httpClientTwitterRegistration,
    c => c.Consumer.ImplementationType == typeof(TwitterBusiness));

var httpClientInstagramRegistration = Lifestyle.Transient.CreateRegistration<HttpClient>(
    () => new HttpClient("https://instagram"),
    container);

container.RegisterConditional(typeof(HttpClient), httpClientInstagramRegistration,
    c => c.Consumer.ImplementationType == typeof(InstagramBusiness));
```

> I'm very curious if I could solve this purely by design

By injecting an `HttpClient` into the `TwitterBusiness` class you get the false sense of flexibility. You seem to be able two swap implementations, but since `HttpClient` is a concrete type, changing implementations makes no sense. Since `TwitterBusiness` communicates directly with `HttpClient`, this should be made an implementation detail. In other words, move the creation of `HttpClient` inside `TwitterBusiness`. Any arguments that you need to configure (an url perhaps) can be injected into `TwitterBusiness`. This way `TwitterBusiness` is in complete control over the creation and disposal of the `HttpClient` and you inject the only thing that is only interesting to change (the url).

Comment: Thanks Steven. I forgot to mention that all of the HttpClient instances are singletons, so the Twitter HttpClient instance will be re-used with the life of the application. I always tend to avoid static variables, but I guess I could have it as a static variable inside TwitterBusiness, and initialize it only once if it's null in the constructor. What do you think? For unit testing I could pass HttpMessageHandler to the constructor.

Comment: @raRaRa you might even register your TwitterBusiness as singleton in case it is stateless (which it typically should). This means your httpclient can still be an instance variable, but I don't think HttpClient is thread-safe. So creating it inside every mrthod would be safest.

Comment: It's thread-safe and should be re-used as much as possible. That's why I want it to be singleton. Otherwise I would just create instance of HttpClient on demand in TwitterBusiness. But you're definitely right, TwitterBusiness could be registered as singleton. I'm going to think this through and try to come up with a decision. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Seems singleton is best: http://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/